# Sorting hard a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a data structure:

```
[{u'inch': [{3.5: u'3 1/2'}, {u'0.340': u'0.340'}, {u'0.560': u'0.560'}]}, {u'mm': [{40.0: Decimal('40.0')}, {70.0: Decimal('70.0')} {50.0: Decimal('50.0')}}]
```

I need to sort it `{**3.5**: u'3 1/2'}`, first value of dict.
I need to get result:

```
[{u'inch': [{u'0.340': u'0.340'}, {u'0.560': u'0.560'}, {3.5: u'3 1/2'}]}, {u'mm': [{40.0: Decimal('40.0')}, {50.0: Decimal('50.0'), {70.0: Decimal('70.0')}}]
```

This code doesn't work:

```
[{k: sorted(v)} for k, v in attr_dict.items()]
```

Comment: in the value of `inch` key, in the first dict the key is float , but others are string?? And when you say `dont work` , what error/unexpected reuslt are you getting?

Comment: realy, i set keys to float and its all works now.